# How to visualize shortest path that is calculated using Networkx?

Tags: python, networkx

I have a graph G (made from a road network shapefile), and a source node S, and a destination node D. I have calculated the length of shortest path using [single_source_dijkstra_path_length](http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.weighted.single_source_dijkstra_path_length.html), but now I need to save the actual path in a shapefile. [This](http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/drawing.html#module-networkx.drawing.nx_pylab) will not help, because it returns the graph representation of my network, which looks nothing like my original network. Is there a way to save this path separately as a shapefile?

Comment: Google helped me find this,http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/drawing.html#module-networkx.drawing.nx_pylab

Comment: Did you use the [`networkx.read_shp`](http://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9/reference/generated/networkx.readwrite.nx_shp.read_shp.html#networkx.readwrite.nx_shp.read_shp) to read in the shapefile?

Comment: @om_henners Yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you read a shapefile in networkx with [`read_shp`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.readwrite.nx_shp.read_shp.html#networkx.readwrite.nx_shp.read_shp) networkx simplifies the line to a start and end, though it keeps all the attributes, and a WKT and WKB representation of the feature for when you export the data again.

To get the subset of the graph `g` based on the shortest path you can simply get the subraph:

```
result_graph = g.subgraph(nx.shortest_path(g, 'from', 'to'))
```

And then you can export the result using [`write_shp`](http://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9/reference/generated/networkx.readwrite.nx_shp.write_shp.html#networkx.readwrite.nx_shp.write_shp). This will write a node shapefile and an edge shapefile to the specified directory.

```
nx.write_shp(result_graph, 'output_directory')
```